# Wrap label in EXTJS

Tags: css, extjs

I'm not able to wrap a label in extjs. I need to set the value dynamically, and when the value is too long, it breaks the layout (which is table layout in my case).

Below is the code which I use:

```
{
    xtype: 'label',
    text: 'Bla bla bla bla bla',
    labelWidth: 20, //had tried width as well, but no use
    labelAlign: 'left',
    autoWidth: false,
    boxMinWidth: 10,
    boxMaxWidth: 20,
    colspan: 1,
    margin: '50 50 50 50'
}
```

I had tried to modify the default extjs css file as well. Added css

```
.x-form-label{
   white-space:normal
}
```

in the `ext-theme-classic-all.css` but of no use.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me in 4.2.1 when wrapping long label text inside a panel is this:

```
{
    xtype: 'label',
    width: '100%',
    text: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx yyyyxx xxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxx aaaa bbbb cccc dddd xxxxxxxxxxxxx yyyyxx xxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxx aaaa bbbb cccc dddd ',
},
```

looks like this in my app in Chrome, FF and IE11:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works in Webkit.

---

```
{
    xtype: "label",
    id: "specificLabel"
}
```

---

```
.x-form-label#specificLabel {
    width: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for the response. I places the code in the ext-theme-classic-all.css file but didn't work. Please let me know if i'm trying this in the right way...

Comment: You'll want to include a final css override for stuff like this I think. (That's how I manage it.)